# How to group columns to sum specific data and sort rows?

Tags: r, match, summarization

Column data is distributed by YEAR, MONTH and DAY, each row is associated to a fourth column named X.

How to obtain the summatory of X at YEAR, MONTH and DAY matched row values and sort the results, for example:

```
A:
year month day x
2000 01    01 50
2000 01    02 30
2002 02    03 50
1994 01    01 3
2000 01    01 50
1996 01    02 5
2000 01    01 10
```

And obtain

```
A:
year month day x
1994 01    01 3
1996 01    02 5
2000 01    01 110
2000 01    02 30
2002 02    03 50
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` is a good option for this:

```
library(dplyr)

A %>% group_by(year, month, day) %>% summarise('x' = sum(x))
```

which gives the desired:

```
 year month day   x
1994    01  01   3
1996    01  02   5
2000    01  01 110
2000    01  02  30
2002    02  03  50
```

Comment: Would you like a grand total all rain value at the bottom as well? Your example result does not show a total for all rain values.

Comment: No, what is said was that your code is showing me only the total summatory

Comment: Philippe, you might clarify your question further then. As far as I can tell what you wanted to obtain and what I provided you seem to match.

Comment: I think OP wants to order by 3 columns (`arrange`) after `summarise`.